# QGIS displays grouped points

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I'm trying to display data from **OSM** (with the **QuickOSM plugin**) and getting strange results.

This is the normal result that I have got until today:

[image]

But I've installed **QGIS** in a brand new computer, and when I ask for the same data, I obtain strange results:

[image]

The points seems to be grouped in a grid.

I'm thinking in some **QGIS** option with the decimal places, or some locale option.

I've changed the *locale* settings to **spain_es**, but still remains the problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what are you looking for exactly?